# parse a string and convert into link in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I need to parse a string like `@[123456:name]`, and what I want to get a like 
`<a href="link/12345/">name</a>`. Is there an easy way to do it? like in facebook we tag someone. i need to create the link like fb is doing using php
[image: FB link]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i try using preg_replace but it is not working for multiple instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function.

```
$re = "/@\\[([^:]+):([^\\]]+)]/m";
$str = "@[123456:name]";
$subst = "<a href=\"link/\1/\">\2</a>";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/oI2jF9/7)

Comment: what about this string? $string = "@[1234343:first] and test is test @[1234343:second]"; it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
preg_replace('/@\[([0-9]*):(.*)\]/', '<a href="link/\1/">\2</a>', $string);
```

Comment: how it will work when there are multple instance like this $string = "@[1234343:first] and test is test @[1234343:second]";